# P&ID Symbol Identification Question

Tags: piping, technical-drawing, instrumentation

Does anyone know what these three symbols are? I am working to identify them but they do not seem to appear in the site: https://www.edrawsoft.com/pid-legend.php

Does anyone know a better reference for P&ID diagram symbols?

[image: Sample from a project I am working on]

Comment: S and B are valves. The other symbol looks like a connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two of those are not standard usage symbols in that way.  You may to have to use context and/or a physical inspection to determine what they are. **Where is that diagram from?**

Various organizations define symbols for piping and/or control.  The *International Society of Automation* uses *ANSI/ISA-5.1-2009*, which you can officially [find on their website](https://www.isa.org/store/products/product-detail/?productId=116630).

1. The **top symbol** is probably meant to be a shut-off valve, probably ball type.  The usual symbol is something like:
   [image: ball valve]
2. The **middle symbol** is a fairly standard **Solenoid-controlled valve**.
3. The **bottom symbol** could be meant to be a butterfly valve (for flow control), or a "blowout" valve / rupture disk (for over-pressure safety).
   The standard symbols for those are like:
   [image: butterfly valve]  **and**  [image: pressure]  **or**  [image]

Comment: I did not know in these drawings that it was a common practice to use non-standard symbols. I was hoping that someone could point me towards a standard list of P&ID symbols, however, if it is common that designers use non-standard symbols that definately leaves more of these drawings up to interpretation that I am used to from an electrical system in the aircraft industry.

Thank you for your reply, I will try and determine from the context of the drawing what the meaning of the symbols are?

Cheers

Comment: Good luck. and let us know what you find.  Unless you are dealing with a (big) government or a (big) company, there are no symbol police and newbies often just pic the most convenient graphic from their template/app that seems to work.